# puppet: Hiera does not like any sub-directories

Tags: puppet, hiera

Can any Puppet and Hiera experts out there help me out with this annoying situation I'm seeing?

Hiera works fine for anything in `common.yaml`:

```
cat common.yaml
---
resolv_conf::nameserver:
- x.x.x.x
- x.x.x.x

profile::ntp::servers:
- x.x.x.x
- x.x.x.x
```

Then tested with the following works:

```
hiera resolv_conf::nameservers environment=production
["x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x"]
```

So, the above works as expected. However, if I use a `nodes` directory inside `hieradata` and add test data in:

```
cat nodes/fqdn.yaml
---
profile::ntp::servers:
-1.1.1.1
-2.2.2.2
```

Then I adjust my `hiera.yaml` file accordingly:

```
cat hiera.yaml
---
:backends: yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata"
:hierarchy:
  -"nodes/%{::fqdn}"
  - "common"

:logger: console
:merge_behavior: native
:deep_merge_options: {}
```

And also add the correct line into the global `hiera.yaml` (both files now look the same for testing).

When testing I get the following error:

```
hiera profile::ntp::servers environment=production -d
```

> DEBUG: xxxxxxxxx: Hiera YAML backend starting
>   DEBUG: xxxxxxxxx: Looking up profile::ntp::servers in YAML backend
>   DEBUG: xxxxxxxxx: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 'nodes/'
>   DEBUG: xxxxxxxxx: Looking for data source common
>   DEBUG: xxxxxxxxx: Found profile::ntp::servers in common
>   ["x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x"]

So it finds the values in `common` but doesn't like the `nodes` directory.

I have tried loads of different variations of the `hierarchy` line in `hiera.yaml`, and many different options everywhere else I can imagine!

There may be typos in the above, as I had to type it all out manually as I have no copy and paste, but I have checked the live files again and again for typos and syntax errors.

Any ideas?

Some updates now I'm home and can copy/paste:

This is on a fresh install of puppet enterprise, using code manager and gitlab.

```
[root@client-01 nodes]# pwd
/root/control-repo/hieradata/nodes
[root@client-01 nodes]# ll
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 34 Jul 13 19:04 puppet.example.com.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 18 Jul 13 18:58 test.yaml
[root@client-01 nodes]# cat puppet.example.com.yaml
---
message:
- "This is in nodes"
```

This is on a dev machine, the repo was then pushed which initiated the hook for code deploy, I've checked that the same data is available in /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production etc on the puppet master. So Code Manager is working.

The following tests on the puppet server:

```
[root@puppet ~]# hostname -f
puppet.example.com
[root@puppet ~]# hiera message environment=production
nil
[root@puppet ~]# hiera message environment=production 
fqdn=puppet.example.com
nil
[root@puppet ~]# hiera message environment=production fqdn=puppet.example.com -d
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 19:28:15 +0100: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 19:28:15 +0100: Looking up message in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 19:28:15 +0100: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 'nodes/'
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 19:28:15 +0100: Looking for data source common
nil
[root@puppet ~]#
```

And so it looks like exactly the same problem:

My `hiera.yaml`:

```
[root@puppet ~]# cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::fqdn}"
  - common

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\code\environments\%{environment}\hieradata on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata"
```

This is somewhat reassuring as it means maybe there isn't something majorly wrong with the other puppet server and more than likely something I'm doing wrong?

FURTHER EDIT:

So I didn't have too much time last night to test things but I did find this:

It looks like the problem is with the facter variables i.e. `"%{::fqdn}"

If I do the following in the root of hieradata:

```
[root@client-01 hieradata]# pwd ; ll ; cat test.yaml
/root/control-repo/hieradata
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4 Jul 13 19:25 common.yaml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 52 Jul 13 19:04 nodes
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 19 Jul 13 21:47 puppet.example.com.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 18 Jul 13 21:43 test.yaml
---
name:
- "jon"
```

Then test with `hiera name environment=production` it works fine.

If I do the following in the root of hieradata:

```
[root@client-01 hieradata]# pwd ; ll ; cat puppet.example.com.yaml
/root/control-repo/hieradata
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4 Jul 13 19:25 common.yaml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 52 Jul 13 19:04 nodes
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 19 Jul 13 21:47 puppet.example.com.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 18 Jul 13 21:43 test.yaml
---
test:
- "pass"
```

Then I test in the following ways:

```
[root@puppet ~]# hostname -f ; hiera test environment=production -d
puppet.example.com
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:44 +0100: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:44 +0100: Looking up test in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:44 +0100: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 
'nodes/'
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:44 +0100: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: ''
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:44 +0100: Looking for data source test
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:44 +0100: Looking for data source common
nil
[root@puppet ~]# hostname -f ; hiera test environment=production 
fqdn=puppet.example.com -d
puppet.example.com
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:57 +0100: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:57 +0100: Looking up test in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:57 +0100: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 
'nodes/'
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:57 +0100: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: ''
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:57 +0100: Looking for data source test
DEBUG: 2017-07-13 21:53:57 +0100: Looking for data source common
nil
```

So disregarding the subfolder of nodes entirely and testing in the root of hieradata shows that yaml files with a fixed name work, but when using facter for a per node lookup... this is where the failure is.

```
[root@puppet ~]# facter fqdn
puppet.example.com
[root@puppet ~]# hostname -f
puppet.example.com
```

However, facter seems to be working just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this and the issue is in fact that the scope indicators need to be included in the facts on the hiera command line.

I.e. instead of:

```
# hiera test environment=production fqdn=puppet.example.com -d
```

you should say:

```
# hiera test environment=production ::fqdn=puppet.example.com -d
```

To reproduce in Rspec-puppet:

```
$ cat manifests/init.pp 
class foo (
  $servers,
  $nameserver,
) {
  notify { "servers: $servers": }
  notify { "nameserver: $nameserver": }
}
```

And

```
$ cat spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml 
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::fqdn}"
  - common
:yaml:
  :datadir: 'spec/fixtures/hieradata'
:logger: console
:merge_behavior: native
:deep_merge_options: {}
```

And

```
$ cat spec/fixtures/hieradata/common.yaml 
---
foo::nameserver:
- 3.3.3.3
- 4.4.4.4

foo::servers:
- 5.5.5.5
- 6.6.6.6
```

And

```
$ cat spec/fixtures/hieradata/nodes/myhost.example.com.yaml 
---
foo::servers:
- 1.1.1.1
- 2.2.2.2
```

And

```
$ cat spec/spec_helper.rb 
require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/module_spec_helper'

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.hiera_config = 'spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml'
  c.default_facts = {
    :fqdn => 'myhost.example.com',
  }
end
```

And

```
$ cat spec/classes/test_spec.rb 
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'foo', :type => :class do
  it { File.write('myclass.json', PSON.pretty_generate(catalogue)) }
end
```

Compile:

```
$ bundle exec rake spec 
...
Finished in 0.15682 seconds (files took 0.97868 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Apply that:

```
$ bundle exec puppet apply --environment=rp_env --catalog=myclass.json 
Notice: servers: [1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Foo/Notify[servers: [1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2]]/message: defined 'message' as 'servers: [1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2]'
Notice: nameserver: [3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Foo/Notify[nameserver: [3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4]]/message: defined 'message' as 'nameserver: [3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4]'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.02 seconds
```

I change the value of fqdn in spec_helper and compile and apply again:

```
$ bundle exec puppet apply --environment=rp_env --catalog=myclass.json 
Notice: servers: [5.5.5.5, 6.6.6.6]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Foo/Notify[servers: [5.5.5.5, 6.6.6.6]]/message: defined 'message' as 'servers: [5.5.5.5, 6.6.6.6]'
Notice: nameserver: [3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Foo/Notify[nameserver: [3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4]]/message: defined 'message' as 'nameserver: [3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4]'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

(rp_env is the magic value for the environment that Rspec-puppet sets.)

So the code works.

But it's the Hiera command line that has issues.

Reproducing your error message:

```
$ bundle exec hiera foo::servers environment=rp_env -d -c spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml 
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:21:54 +1000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:21:54 +1000: Looking up foo::servers in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:21:54 +1000: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 'nodes/'
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:21:54 +1000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:21:54 +1000: Found foo::servers in common
["5.5.5.5", "6.6.6.6"]
```

Attempt to set the fact on the command line using the same syntax you did:

```
$ bundle exec hiera foo::servers fqdn=myhost.example.com environment=rp_env -d -c spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml 
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:23:34 +1000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:23:34 +1000: Looking up foo::servers in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:23:34 +1000: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 'nodes/'
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:23:34 +1000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:23:34 +1000: Found foo::servers in common
["5.5.5.5", "6.6.6.6"]
```

Finally providing the missing scope indicator:

```
$ bundle exec hiera foo::servers ::fqdn=myhost.example.com environment=rp_env -d -c spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml 
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:24:09 +1000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:24:09 +1000: Looking up foo::servers in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:24:09 +1000: Looking for data source nodes/myhost.example.com
DEBUG: 2017-07-15 13:24:09 +1000: Found foo::servers in nodes/myhost.example.com
["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"]
```

Hooray it works.

Agree that's pretty confusing.

See also [here](https://ask.puppet.com/question/30040/puppet-4-not-using-custom-facts/).

Comment: Fantastic work thank you so much. I'm fairly new to puppet, I'm doing the course and have booked the Exam, but my requirements are rapidly out weighing my knowledge. I'd not heard of Rspec-Puppet. Been reading about it now, it looks very interesting. - I found last night actually that despite my errors hiera is actually working and if I use puppet lookup as opposed to the hiera binary, it works fine. So maybe this is a limitation with the hiera binary. Thanks for the explanation and the work around though, it's going to take some understanding but I have just checked with ::fqdn= and it works.

Comment: Rspec-puppet is the thing they won't tell you about in Puppet Fundamentals, but I find that it is one of the most useful things to understand. When you have the test harness set up, all of a sudden it is really easy to test and debug Puppet code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `hiera.yaml` you have:

```
-"nodes/%{::fqdn}"
```

In there, `%{::fqdn}` refers to the Facter fact `fqdn`.

Meanwhile you created a file called `nodes/fqdn.yaml`.

Hiera would not see that file unless your `fqdn` fact was literally returning `fqdn` (rather than something like `myhost.example.com`).

It should find the file if you instead say:

```
hiera profile::ntp::servers environment=production fqdn=fqdn -d
```

However what you probably want to do is rename the Hiera file/s to match your nodes' actual FQDNs, i.e.

```
cat nodes/myhost.example.com.yaml
---
profile::ntp::servers:
-1.1.1.1
-2.2.2.2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned.. the file does say the fqdn.. but I didn't want to write the fqdn in the above. Was trying to put things non-specific and I should have mentioned that.. my bad.

Comment: I created the file as such: vim $(hostname -f).yaml

Comment: Does the line: "Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy" usually mean that the fact on the end cannot be read by facter? I've been thinking the problem was with my syntax or my understanding of Hiera. Which is probably also true :)

Comment: This is a valid assumption and correction based on the question. It was also my first guess, but the output made me rethink it when it seemed like Hiera was finding that priority correctly.

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid I stopped reading when I saw `cat nodes/fqdn.yaml`. :)

Answer (score 1):

The key information from the debug output is:

> DEBUG: xxxxxxxxx: Ignoring bad definition in :hierarchy: 'nodes/'

This should be an indication that your YAML hieradata for that lookup priority has a syntax error. Sure enough, if we use an online validation tool like http://www.yamllint.com, we see it has a syntax error. Change your hieradata file to:

```
# nodes/myhost.example.com.yaml
---
profile::ntp::servers:
- 1.1.1.1
- 2.2.2.2
```

and it should work fine.

I recommend in the future to use a tool or some code to validate your code and data so you can identify these issues faster and easier. I have written a popular one for that, but will refrain from plugging it as I think StackOverflow may not be happy about that.

Comment: If your tool is relevant to the answer, plug away surely? :)

Comment: I'm afraid it looks like you've found one of my typos as I wrote it all out by hand.. I couldn't copy and paste. The spaces are in the original, and I've ran all other files through the website you mentioned and all say Valid YAMLs.

Comment: It's late here so if it's still not working I'll try to reproduce it tomorrow.

Comment: No problem ,thank you. I am home now and I'm even more convinced I'm doing something wrong as the same thing happens on my test lab. I will investigate more and post updates.

Comment: I have edited my original post with some more information. Thanks, Jon.